# Hide columns in excel based on drop down list selection

Tags: excel, show-hide

I am wondering if it is possible to hide columns based on the selection of a drop down list using excel.
For example say i have 3 columns( C1,C2,C3) and i have a drop-down list with 2 values(drop1 and drop2). When drop1 is selected from the dropdown list then show C1,C2 and hide C3. When drop2 is selected show all Columns C1,C2,C3 . Does anyone know if this is possible in excel ?

Comment: asking a broad question like this will get you a broad answer usually as well... I have tried my best in my answer to be as narrow as possible.

Answer (score 0):

[Here's an example](http://www.techrepublic.com/forum/questions/42-177201/excel-vba-to-hide-a-column-unhide-it) of hiding columns via VBA. You'd need to write code much like that.

Mind you, I'm assuming that when you say "excel" you actually mean within the excel application. If you're generating the Excel file programmatically, you could easily use similar code via the OpenXML API.

Comment: no i am just using an excel document, i have some programming knowledge but i have never really done any VBA with excel before

Comment: In  that case the answer is No. You will have to do something programmatically to get this working. However by using the Record Macro button under the Developer tab you will be very much assisted by Microsoft already!

Comment: Got it working using VBA.Code follows:                                                                Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim CustName As String

CustName = Worksheets("Customer Timesheet").Range("F7").Value
If CustName = "Customer 1" Then
Worksheets("Customer Timesheet").Columns("H").Hidden = False

Else
Worksheets("Customer Timesheet").Columns("H").Hidden = True

End If
End Sub

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible (very short answer).

Use VBA for it in which case you will have to link the drop down value to either a cell (and use Worksheet_Change to see if the particular cell has taken the required value for hiding the column or not (in which case hiding should be undone).